# CSP Response Headers within an Angular web.config not applied

Tags: angular, iis

I have deployed an Angular app that implements a CSP where the Response Headers are set via the IIS Manager. This works as advertised. Meaning, that I can see the CSP in the response headers and the OWASP is clean.

However, I would prefer to have the headers set via a web.config file as below. So, I removed the CSP that I set up through IIS Manager and redeployed the Angular app. The app runs and works as expected, but the CSP is no longer being applied.

1. my knowledge of IIS is minimalistic at best,
2. the rewrite rule is working because the app is functional and I can see it via the IIS Manager,
3. I can see that the headers are set (looking at them through IIS Manager), however, they do not seem to have any effect or they aren't being applied. I know this because I viewed the responses in debug and did not see them and I ran OWASP. OWASP is now reporting many alerts

Any help is greatly appreciated

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block" />
        <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
        <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; 
        style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; font-src 'self' data:;
        img-src 'self' data:; frame-ancestors 'self'; form-action 'self';" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>

    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I think you need to use failed request tracing to check if custom header module set reponse headers. If any other function cover to modify the headers, FRT log will also show that. You can view log get it.

Comment: That sounds like a great idea, I'll check it out and let you know...thx

Comment: No errors seem to be appearing

Comment: The purpose of using FRT is not to see if there is an error, but to see what IIS modules have modified to the response headers.